# Update existing records table with ID of foreign key table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following tables:

[image: Diary Table]

and

[image: History Table]

I recently added the [History Table ID] column and added a Foreign Key Reference to the History table.  What has to happen is, the Value of the [History Table ID] column has to be updated with the ID value of the History table.  I have already been able to get it right with 2 entries, the entries that have the ID of Diary table in the Description column of the History table.  This query below accomplishes that:

```
Update Diary 
SET [History Table ID] = History.ID
from History with (nolock)
WHERE [Lookup Table HA] = 7 
and [Lookup Table HAS] = 19 
and Description LIKE 'Diary item (%'
and PATINDEX('%)%', Description) > 13
and Dairy.ID = SUBSTRING(Description, 13, PATINDEX('%)%', Description)-13)
```

Is there any way that the rest can be updated at all?  I just can't get my head around this.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Please see below for Updated Table shots:  This is where my problem in Updating and joining lies:

[image: Updated Diary and History]

Comment: From screenshots, it seems between two tables, the columns "UserAssignedBy","IssueNumber","GlobalId"  for table "Diary" have composite key corresponds to "UsersAssignedFor","IssueNumber","GlobalId" for History table. Is it so ???

Comment: is there a typo in the last row in "Dairy.ID"?

Comment: @Pranav, in this case I assigned issues to myself, but normally the UserAssignedFor and UserAssignedBy will be different, as a manager will assign issues to employees.  IssueNumber will always be the same.  GlobalId will also always be the same in both tables.

Comment: @Der U, no no typo ignore the last row.  This is when the user has not selected anything and made a normal entry.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this isn't correct, but it looks like the `Global Id` (and `Issue number`) connects the two tables.  If so, you can do:

```
Update Diary 
    SET [History Table ID] = History.ID
    from History with (nolock)
    WHERE Diary.[Global ID] = History.[Global ID] and
          Diary.[Issue number] = History.[Issue number];
```

Otherwise, you need to figure out the logic that connects one record in `History` to a record in the `Diary` table.

EDIT:

Let me assume you want the biggest history id when there are multiple matches:

```
Update Diary 
    SET [History Table ID] = h.ID
    from (select [Global ID], [Issue number], max(id) as maxid
          from History with (nolock)
          group by [Global ID], [Issue number]
         ) h 
    WHERE Diary.[Global ID] = h.[Global ID] and
          Diary.[Issue number] = h.[Issue number];
```

Comment: My mistake. @Gordon Linoff  The Global Id is unfortunately not sufficient as it corresponds to the IssueNumber.  In both History and Diary there can be more than one instance with the same IssueNumber. e.g. G00001 which will have a globalId of 1. The same in History.  So, joining with [Global ID] is not sufficient.  My screenshots doesn't point that out, my apologies.

Comment: @frans . . . Then add `Issue Number` into the logic.

Comment: there can be multiple records in both table with the same [Global ID] and [Issue number].  So, 1, G0000001 can be present 3 times in Diary and 20 times in History.  That's what makes it so difficult.

Comment: @frans . . . You have to choose which one for the update (or an arbitrary one will be chosen).

Comment: I hear you.  But, this is the way the database was designed and tables were designed.  With the above query, it updates all Issue Numbers with the same ID value.  Which doesn't correspond with the History tables auto-generated ID's.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in comment, "IssueNumber will always be the same. GlobalId will also always be the same in both tables." So this will work fine:

```
 UPDATE Diary 
      SET [History Table ID] = History.ID
    FROM History WITH (NOLOCK)
      WHERE Diary.[Global ID] = History.[Global ID]
         AND Diary.IssueNumber = History.IssueNumber
```

Comment: I think my images might be a bit misleading.  There can be more than one Issue Number with the same value, meaning there will be more than on GlobalId with the same value as this corresponds to the issue number.  The same with History.  Remember, this updates all records.  In my images, there record 7 and 8 are updated already with the query I posted in the question.  The above query you supplied updates everything.  My images might be a little misleading.  Apologies again.

Comment: Does this anything to do with  "[Lookup Table HA] = 7 
and [Lookup Table HAS] = 19 " condition ? It's present in your code not here...

Comment: [Lookup Table HA] has value 7 for a Diary items added, and [Lookup Table HAS] has 19.  So, this just refers to Diary items being added but can't be used alone.